# XMLHttpRequest() after submit from form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript, can I use `XMLHttpRequest()` after I hit submit from form but the result should be the same as onclick event. I have a function named `get` and by using `XMLHttpRequest()` I can add a new object within the div `sample`, it works if it's a button. The only difference is that I want to add new object to the div `sample` without redirecting to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/get?query=apple` after I submit the form, form and function get() should be working together in this case. And also I don't want to see the `http://127.0.0.1:5000/get?query=apple` in the browser's url field after I submit the form. I need some help, I push myself to use pure js as possible and not to rely on jquery.

```
<div id="sample"></div>

<div onclick="get('apple');">CLICK APPLE</div>

<form action="/get" method="GET">
    <input name="query">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    function get(query) {
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML =
              this.responseText;
            }
          };
          xhttp.open("GET", "get?query=" + query, true);
          xhttp.send();
        };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can interrupt submit event, and do whatever you want.

```
<div id="sample"></div>

<div onclick="get('apple');">CLICK APPLE</div>

<form id="form">
    <input name="query">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
    document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var query = e.target.elements['query'].value;
        get(query);
    });

    function get(query) {
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML =
              this.responseText;
            }
          };
          xhttp.open("GET", "get?query=" + query, true);
          xhttp.send();
        };
</script>
```

Comment: This actually works but the result is `/get?query=[object%20HTMLInputElement]` instead of `/get?query=STRING_FROM_QUERY_VALUE`. How do we convert that object to a string?

Comment: Edited it , check now.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function get(query) {
  console.log("Called Function");
  query = document.getElementById('query').value;
  console.log(query);
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML =
        this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "get?query=" + query, true);
  xhttp.send();
};
```

```html
<div id="sample"></div>
<div onclick="get('apple');">CLICK APPLE</div>
<form id="myForm" action="/get" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="query" id="query">
   <input type="button" onclick="get()" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

You have user Form type `method="GET"` which changed to `method="POST"` and added `onclick="get()"` to call the function from javaScript

Comment: Your answer works only if the `onclick="get()"` has a predefined object inside like `onclick="get('banana')"` but how can I attached the value of `name="query"` inside the get function?

Comment: @NinjaWarrior11 answer updated bro you need to use `document.getElementById('query').value` to get input value.

Comment: @NinjaWarrior11 Welome Bro :-)